# CPU burst longer than quantum?

Tags: operating-system

In a quiz answer, our instructor claimed cpu burst can be short and longer than the quantum. It easy to see how it can be shorter. But how it can be longer?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer. When running system function that disable interrupt (including clock interrupt), process run till restore the interrupt. Then, the time used can be longer than quantum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Burst Time can be greater than Quantum that's why processor preempts resources from running process and assign them to some other process.
See this example:

- Process1 has Burst Time = 5 seconds and arrives before Process2
- Process2 has Burst Time = 6 seconds
- Quantum = 3 seconds

See both processes has `burst time > quantum` so when Process1 runs and completes its quantum of 3 seconds it will be preemptive and Process2 will be given the resources and after that Process2 will be preempted and Process1 will be given the resources, this will continue until processes are not completed.
[Graphical Explanation of the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpud5.png)